# Why 'prange' is not effective?

Tags: python, cython

I try to use 'prange' to accelerate for loop. But it's not useful. There is almost no change in the comparison time. And I also tried 'pool.map' to accelerate the loop. It also has little effect. I give two formats of cython code, which are used for prange and pool.map respectively. Can you give me some advices?

```
#This is my cython code
cimport cython
import cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from cython.parallel import prange,parallel

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.nonecheck(False)

cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t,ndim=3] _conv2d_k(np.ndarray[np.float32_t,ndim=4] input,np.ndarray[np.float32_t,ndim=4] filter):

   cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t,ndim=3] output = np.zeros((3,17,17),dtype=np.float32)
   cdef unsigned int i,j,di,dj,cl,k
   cdef np.float32_t t=0
   for k in prange(3,nogil=True):
       for di in range(0,6):
          for dj in range(0,6):
              for i in range(0,17):
                  for j in range(0,17):
                    for cl in range(0,256):
                        output[k,i,j]+=input[k,i + di, j + dj, cl]*filter[k,di, dj, cl]

   output = 0.001 * output - 4.184

   return output
def conv2d_k(a,b):
    return _conv2d_k(a,b)
```

```
#for pool.map()
cimport cython
import cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.nonecheck(False)

cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t,ndim=2] _conv2d_i(np.ndarray[np.float32_t,ndim=3] input,np.ndarray[np.float32_t,ndim=3] filter):

   cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t,ndim=2] output = np.zeros((17,17),dtype=np.float32)
   cdef unsigned int i,j,di,dj,cl
   cdef np.float32_t t=0

   for di in range(0,6):
      for dj in range(0,6):
          for i in range(0,17):
              for j in range(0,17):
                for cl in range(0,256):
                    output[i,j]+=input[i + di, j + dj, cl]*filter[di, dj, cl]
   output = 0.001 * output - 4.184
   return output
def conv2d_i(a,b):
    return _conv2d_i(a,b)
```

```
# my python code
import numpy as np
import time
import threading
import multiprocessing
import conv2d_k
import conv2d_i
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
def job(z):
   return conv2d_i.conv2d_i(z[0], z[1])

def main():
   input=np.random.rand(3,22, 22,256).astype(np.float32)
   kernel=np.random.rand(3,6,6,256).astype(np.float32)
   start1 = time.time()
   for i in range(3):
       conv2d_i.conv2d_i(input[i], kernel[i])
   end1=time.time()
   print(end1-start1)
   # ----------------------------
   pool = ThreadPool(3)
   data=[(input[0],kernel[0]),(input[1],kernel[1]),(input[2],kernel[2])]
   start2 = time.time()
   pool.map(job,data)
   end2 = time.time()
   print(end2 - start2)

   # ----------------------------
   start3=time.time()
   output2=conv2d_k.conv2d_k(input,kernel)
   end3=time.time()
   print(end3-start3)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

```
for loop time:0.012341022491455078
pool.map() time:0.013735532760620117
prange time:0.013698816299438477
```

Comment: How are you compiling it? You do need to ensure openMP is enabled with your compiler.... (There's also a lot of pointless non-optimization here, e.g. `cdivision(False)`, but no division anywhere, and writing `cdef` functions that you immediately wrap in a `def` function. However, that's pretty tangential to your question)